# AWS ECS - how to log to cloudwatch from ECS container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, docker

I have a container that runs a given task in an ECS cluster. I'd like to log the results of that task in cloudwatch.

I've attempted to edit the container to use `awslogs` and set the following params:

- `awslogs-group`
- `awslogs-region`

[image]

When I attempt to run the task, I get the following helpful error:

[image]

Is there a proven MVP way of setting up containers to log to cloudwatch in AWS?

Comment: Have you been following this? https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/awslogs/

I think you haven't set the credentials correctly. Are you using instance profile?

Answer (score 0):

We are using a docker-container which is forwarding all logfiles to AWS CloudWatch:

https://github.com/nearform/docker-cloudwatch

First, we have created a new IAM user with the required access rights and assigned it to the new IAM user. With the Access ID / Key it is now possible to have all logs from all containers in Cloudwatch.

Answer (score 0):

You should add another parameter in "options" of "logConfiguration" inside "containerDefinitions" like this:

```
"logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/<your-task-name>",
                    "awslogs-region": "ap-south-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            }
```

If you want to use other log driver take a look at [these examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html) on AWS docs and documentation for logging part [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_storage).