# Why does Python logging work in local docker comtainer but not on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, logging, amazon-ec2

If I understood correctly, docker writes everything that is printed to the console in a log file. I can get the path to the log file with `docker inspect *container_name* | grep LogPath`

If i run the container and check the log locally, the result is what i would expect - every executed print statement can be found in the file. I can do the same thing on my EC2 instance on AWS but there, only error messages are written in the log file, no normal print statements.

How can i set the logging level on AWS to include every print statement?

Comment: Are you running docker using ECS?

Comment: yes i do - is there an option for this in the task definition?

Comment: This is an option - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471668/aws-ecs-how-to-log-to-cloudwatch-from-ecs-container

Comment: I know there are different options for logging but this doesn't answer my question of why the logs are there locally but not on AWS. Shouldn't the container be the same by definition?

Comment: @OleBialas Have you found an answer to this?